# How can I read the Accelerometer using codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I think, since I can't find any docs on this at this point, that there isn't an interface / ActionListener on the accelerometer in Codename One? If there is please could somebody point me to the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't at this point in time. You can use [NativeInterfaces](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to call native code to handle the accelerometer capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but may have a project in the future that would use these sensors also, so I came across this on the [CN1Libs page](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html)

https://github.com/chen-fishbein/sensors-codenameone